# Queue job with 4 hours delay

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I have a mission-critical queue in laravel 5.4 which is powerd by Redis and 8 workers on supervisor.

In this queue, I have to make delayed jobs with a delay about 4 hours like this:

```
        $job = (new VerifyAndOrderJob($books))
            ->onQueue('orders')
            ->delay(\Carbon::now()->addHours(4));


        dispatch($job);
```

Now since Laravel queues are based on FIFO, If I have thousands of delayed jobs like this in the queue everyday and I wanted to push a same job but without any delay, is it need to wait till other delayed jobs to be processed or this will be fired instantly?

Comment: You should probably just use a different queue for non delayed tasks